# Why I cannot use IBOutlet named "title" in cocoa?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have view controller, and inside I have `IBOutlet UITextField *title` , which is connected with some UITextField in .xib file. When I try to push this view controller to navigation controller, my app throws NSException. And when I change the name of IBOutlet, everything is ok. I saw some guys here had similar issue, but I'm asking WHY is it so ? Is it some kind of reserved word or some bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`UIViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) already has a title property that is of type `NSString`. This is the title you normally see in a navigation conroller. Use a better name like `titleLabel` otherwise there will be a race to set title, depending on when set it will be an `NSString` and others some UI element. Your scenario it sounds like the title was set to a UI element and when your navigation controller goes to display it, it is sending a message for NSString which will result in an exception.

Answer (score 0):

`UIViewController` already has a property called `title` that is conflicting with the IBOutlet.

Answer (score 0):

UIViewController already has a property named title.  You cannot create another property using the same name.  Choose a better name.